# How do I model a charge source in SPICE?

Tags: sensor, ltspice

I would like to model a force sensor based on a piezoelectric crystal that generates 10pC/N and has a static capacitance of 20pF in LTSpice for simulation purposes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model this sensor as a voltage source with a series 20pF capacitor. The source voltage is analogous to the sensed force, where 1N of force corresponds to 0.5V.

Comment: Could you explain the derivation of 1N = 0.5V? 

Is this the ratio of charge generation to the static capacitance?

Comment: The piezo crystal acts as a capacitor with a parallel charge source (i.e., a current source of value \$\rm{d}Q/\rm{d}t\$). This can be Thevenized into a voltage source with series capacitor where the capacitance is 20pF and the voltage source value creates the same open-circuit voltage and short-circuit charge displacement. Open-circuit, a 10pC/N charge source fed into 20pF produces 0.5V/N (because \$V=Q/C\$), so this is what the voltage source should be. Checking that short-circuit displacement is the same, a 0.5V/N voltage source fed into a 20pF capacitor displaces 10pC/N -- the model works.